# Updating Label Text several times while a Button is pressed in Swift

Tags: swift, label

in my swift project I have a button and there are many works that I need to be done when I press the button (lets say these works take around 40 seconds from the moment I press the button). Therefore, during this period of time my button is in its "selected" state. What I want is to changing the text of a label several times (each after specific functions are done) while this button is pressed. So I have something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Some huge functions which take 10 seconds to run
    self.myLabel.text = "Some text1"

    //Some other huge functions which take 10 seconds to run
    self.myLabel.text = "Some text2"

    //Some other other huge functions which take 10 seconds to run
    self.myLabel.text = "Some text3"

    //Some other other other huge functions which take 10 seconds to run
    self.myLabel.text = "Some text4"
}
```

But when I click the button all these functions start running and they finish but I only see the text of myLabel is changing to "Some text4", It will never change to "Some text1" or "Some text2" or "Some text3" before becoming "Some text4". I thought maybe putting **DispatchQueue.main.async { }** will help but still doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: these function are executed within micro second

Comment: I know that is exactly my problem. My functions take too long so I should be able to see the changes, why I do not see them? 
Let say self.myLabel.text = "Some text1" takes 1 micro second then I have huge functions after that which will take 10 seconds After 10 seconds, self.myLabel.text = "Some text2" should be run so I should be able to see self.myLabel.text = "Some text1" for 10 seconds !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run all of your long-running tasks in a background queue, and make the label updates in the main queue.    The key is to call the next function only when the first is finished, or they will run in parallel, and could all update at the same time.  Here's an example

```
func doSomething1() {
    // as good a way as any to simulate a long-running process
    sleep(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myLabel.text = "Some text1"
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.doSomething2()
    }
}
func doSomething2() {
    sleep(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myLabel.text = "Some text2"
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.doSomething3()
    }
}
func doSomething3() {
    sleep(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myLabel.text = "Some text3"
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.doSomething4()
    }
}
func doSomething4() {
    sleep(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myLabel.text = "Some text4"
    }
}

@IBAction func cmdDoStuff(_ sender: UIButton) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.doSomething1()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is synchronous, code on the line is executed immeadiately after the code on the previous line. So you will always see just last setted text `"Some text4"`

To call some code after something is done we're using completion handlers in Swift

```
func call(_ completion: @escaping (String)->Void) {
    completion("SomeText")
}
```

call completion from inside of the method in the moment when you need to, let's say, task is done. Then code inside completion parameter gets executed

```
call { text in // calling method
    self.myLabel.text = text // this is called after you call completion(:) from inside `call(:)`
}
```

---

So let's try it with this demo

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    callAfter(2, text: "Text1") { text in
        print(text)
    }

    callAfter(4, text: "Text2") { text in
        print(text)
    }

    callAfter(6, text: "Text3") { text in
        print(text)
    }

}

func callAfter(_ duration: Double, text: String, _ completion: @escaping (String)->Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration) {
        completion(text)
    }
}
```

... you should be able to see printed `Text1`, `Text2`, `Text3` in periods 2, 4, 6 seconds from the moment when button was pressed

Answer (score 0):

Add completion block to your function. Then change the label text inside completion block

```
typealias completionBlock = () -> Void

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    firstFunction {
        self.myLabel.text = "Some text1"
    }

    secondFunction {
        self.myLabel.text = "Some text2"
    }

    thirdFuntion {
        self.myLabel.text = "Some text3"
    }
}

func firstFunction(_ completion: @escaping completionBlock) {
    // your function body
    completion()
}

func secondFunction(_ completion: @escaping completionBlock) {
    // your function body
    completion()
}

func thirdFuntion(_ completion: @escaping completionBlock) {
    // your function body
    completion()

}
```